# How to test if a string contains numbers at certain points

Tags: java, string, bluej

I have a string with 6 characters in length. The first character must be a 
capital letter, and the last 5 characters must be digits.

I need to write 
code to return true if the characters that follow after the capital letter 
are digits, and false if they are not.

Here is what I have so far, but when 
testing the code, I get an error:

```
public boolean hasValidDigits(String s)
{
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(1-5))) {
        return true;
    } else {
             return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Write a [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 4):

Next time please put the error description.
What you need here is Regex  which test the string to the pattern.

i.e.:

```
return s.matches("[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}");
```

`[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}` means: one capital letter, and 5 digits after.

Comment: i think you don't need to use `{1}`

Answer (score 0):

Check str.matches("[A-Z][0-9]{5}");